# Greyscale Google Map then colour on hover?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently trying to make a google map that's embeded on my website greyscale, which so far I have done with css3, But I want it to change to it's original colours when you hover over it. The css3 hover isn't working so is there a way with jquery at all?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm currently just using CSS. It manages to make it greyscale but doesn't allow the hover.

Comment: .map2 {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}

map2:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `.` before the second map2.

Comment: I'm an idiot. That's what happens when you stare at it too long. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! I know the feeling, believe me…